# UML approach for a SharePoint project

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have to realise a SharePoint application, so I have to do the conception of this project, but when I search in internet i don't find anything like UML approach for Sharepoint project,

so my quesion is : there is an approach UML (i.e Class diagrams, Use Case etc) for a SharePoint project? or there is another approach for this kind of approach ?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have found is the Patterns & Practices site for SharePoint 2010.

https://spg.codeplex.com/

You can find recommended patterns that can be used with the SSOM in 2013 for you UML based architecture I guess.